# Build maven with Accessmbly plugin failed

Tags: maven, plugins

I am new to maven,I would like to use Accessmbly to package an executable jar.
But I met an issue when execute "mvn -e -X assembly:assembly" in command line.
Could anyone help me?Thanks in advance.
The issue like
[issue error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZHRzk.png)
My pom configuration as following,regarding the plugin configuration please refer picture5[configuration1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8lfGL.png)[configuration2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iEJ5h.png) [configuration3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wQt5U.png) [configuration4](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YD4u8.png) [configuration5](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MT9Hs.png)

Comment: What configuration? Please [EDIT](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/51647730/edit) your question and include it.

Comment: Do not make links to images better post the text into the post...

Comment: I am trying to paste the text of configuration and errors,but they are too long,and it always remind me format error.

Comment: Based on what I saw you should remove all usage of maven-assembly-plugin, resources-plugin, maven-jar-plugin, manually configuring `src/main/resources` etc. cause you have a spring boot parent which means follow the docs and let spring-maven-plugin handle the packaging....

Comment: Thanks for your comment.I just want to try the maven-assembly-plugin and see its magic.Maybe I should try a easy project not current project and see.